Я случайно создал локальный репозиторий в корневой папке сисетмы (в /Users/ananaj1). Как можно удалить этот репозиторий не удаляя файлов системы?
Во время обучения git случайно был создан локальный репозиторий в корневой папке. Теперь в корневой папке сидит репозиторий. Как можно удалить этот репозиторий без удаления системных файлов.

Какая ОС, не Windows?

У меня ос: mac os

Удали папку .git из этой директории (только она скрытая если что)
